# How do I use the Grails environment settings in micronaut client @Header?

Tags: spring-boot, micronaut, grails-4, micronaut-client

I have an environment-specific header property in my Grails `application.yml`, configured like so:

```
environments:
    development:
        apiKey: 'foo'
```

How do I use this setting in a `@Header` for the micronaut HTTP declarative client?

I tried this:

```
// property placeholder resolver seems to interprept 'apiKey' property as 'api-key'
@Header(name = 'apikey', value = '${api-key}')
```

but I got this error:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not resolve placeholder ${api-key}
    at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver$PlaceholderSegment.getValue(DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.java:283)
    at io.micronaut.context.env.DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(DefaultPropertyPlaceholderResolver.java:95)
    at io.micronaut.inject.annotation.EnvironmentAnnotationValue.lambda$new$0(EnvironmentAnnotationValue.java:48)
    at io.micronaut.core.annotation.AnnotationValue.getRawSingleValue(AnnotationValue.java:953)
    at io.micronaut.core.annotation.AnnotationValue.stringValue(AnnotationValue.java:482)
    at io.micronaut.core.annotation.AnnotationValue.stringValue(AnnotationValue.java:514)
    at io.micronaut.http.client.interceptor.HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.intercept(HttpClientIntroductionAdvice.java:207)
```

Also, this header may not be needed in all environments (in this case, it will be set to the empty string). Will the @Header handle this? Or do I need to do something different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Micronaut doesn't support reading `environments.development` in application.yml. If you move your config to `application-development.yml` then it will be read by both Grails and Micronaut.

Comment: Thanks! I will try this